# ¿Por qué no puedo pasar propiedades de un formulario a otro en VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, vb

Tengo la siguiente propiedad en un formulario:

```
Private m_var As Integer


Public Property Var As Integer
    Get
        Return m_var
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        m_var = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Y le hago un set de un valor:

```
Me.Var = 5
```

Sin embargo, cuando abro otro formulario y llamo a la propiedad de este formulario, el valor está a 0.

```
Dim num = Form1.Var
```

Esto me devuelve 0. ¿Por qué no puedo usar el valor que le asigno en el anterior formulario?

Comment: Te recomiendo que edites la pregunta, y pongas en contexto como instancias el `Form`, seteas el valor, y cómo intentas accederlo luego.

Comment: Cada instancia que hagas del formulario tiene su propiedad. Es decir, cada vez que hagas `Form1 f = New Form1`, f.var será 0. Estos son conceptos básicos de POO.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un `Form` no es mas que una clase, que tiene como propiedad particular que hereda de un objeto que sabe como dibujarla en pantalla.

Sin embargo, no deja de ser una clase.

Por lo tanto, instanciar varias veces la misma clase, no provoca que tenga las propiedades iguales, como funciona con cualquier objeto.

Cuando uno instancia un `Form`, no esta instancia una clase que es única para el programa, uno puede instanciar un montón de forms, y son todos distintos.

El problema es pensar que como es un `Form`, es único dentro del sistema. Tu programa no sabe que forms hay o no hay. Entonces, por instanciar uno nuevo, no estamos llamando a uno que ya existe, por mas que sea el mismo `Form`(clase). Es uno nuevo.

Esto es un error común. Pensar que como es un `Form`no es una clase como el resto provoca este tipo de confusiones. Ten en cuenta también, que si abres un `Form`, y pierdes su referencia, va a quedar huérfano como cualquier otra clase en tu programa. Y lo peor, es que en este caso, va a quedar una ventana abierta, sobre la cual nadie tiene control.

Para contestar tu pregunta, si puedes pasar propiedades a un `Form`, así como se las pasas a cualquier clase.

Comment: Exacto. Ese era el problema que tenía, por instanciar el formulario. Muchas gracias.